# Which statistical test is more appropriate?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, manova

I have collected data for an experimental study from 88 participants. Specifically, all participants received both interventions but in a different order. 44 participants received firstly Treatment A and then Treatment B, and 44 participants received firstly Treatment B and then treatment A.

My question is which is the most appropriate test to examine differences both between individuals and within the same person? I want to examine:

(a) Whether Treatment A is more effective than Treatment B within the same person,

and

(b) In the two-time points separately which treatment is more effective across people. Which test do you think should i run in SPSS? I was thinking of two-way repeated measures ANOVA but I am not sure whether it gives you both between and within-group results.